# Catching route with parentheses in the path

Tags: node.js, regex, express, url-routing

I have a NodeJS web application. I disseminated one route with this text:

```
great impact (learn more at emotionathletes.org/impact)
```

The route `/impact` exists, the route `/impact)` does not. Some email clients include the closing parenthesis in the route and I would like to redirect it. If I use:

```
router.get("/impact)", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/impact");
});
```

I get this error:

```
~/emotionathletes/server/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js:128
  return new RegExp(path, flags);
         ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/impact)\/?$/: Unmatched ')'
```

I understand that route strings serve as input to regular expressions, where parentheses serve to catch groups, and thus cannot contain parenthesis. Using HTML entities such as `/impact%29` does not catch the route `/impact)`.

One solution is a generic handler such as:

```
router.get("/:token", async (req, res, next) => {

  // Remove parenthesis in the route path.
  let newPath = req.originalUrl.replace(")", "").replace("(", "");
  if (newPath != req.originalUrl) {
    return res.redirect(newPath);
  }

  // Any other routes, such as 404.
  // ...
}
```

What is the proper way to catch routes with parentheses in NodeJS?

Comment: As ugly as it looks, try `"/login\\\)"``

Comment: Yes, this works, can you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use unicode expression [ \u0029 = `)`] with regex

`router.get(/impact\u0029/, (req, res) => { ... }`

I think your second approach is more appropriate if you have multiple routes having the same issue. If there is only one route, then you can use the above solution.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it mentions regular expressions in routes.